# Update Manager in Ubuntu 12.04 is not working

Tags: update-manager

```
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.canonical.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I get the above lines when I try to install my upgrades in my Ubuntu 12.04. I have a working internet connection where im able to browse pls help. Whenever I check it shows the number of upgrades available but it doesn't download any.

Kindly help, balasubramani.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally the servers seem to go a bit haywire. I had it happen to my today. All I did to solve it was to go to the Ubuntu Software Center, from the menu select Edit | Software Sources. This will show you "Download From". Mine was set to the US and I changed it to Australia.

Reload and then update.

The quicky is to edit the file /etc/apt/sources.list and change all the repositories that start with "us." to "au.". Only do this if you are comfortable with the linux command line.

Good luck...